# How does 13.04 stack up to 12.04 in terms of battery life?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, 13.04, battery

I've been having some issues with battery life, perhaps due in part to the age of the battery, but I'd like to squeeze out every last minute I can. I've heard that 13.04 is developed with mobile devices in mind and has some emphasis on battery life. Can any laptop users report on how it has positively (or negatively) affected their battery life, in relation to 12.04/12.10?

Comment: battery life on my notebook went from 1:50-ish to 2:10-ish. 1 problem... I used jupiter on <=12.10 and have switched to TLP. So  actually comparing is pretty impossible.

Comment: I have Jupiter installed as well as TLP. Does this work to the detriment of power savings or does it not matter much?

The only difference I noticed between TLP and laptop-mode-tools is a small (< 1 sec) difference in shutdown time, but TLP doesn't include nifty charger in/out scripts like laptop-mode did :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact that it uses less resources and is therefore faster, and the kernel has better power management, Ubuntu 13.04 has better battery life than Ubuntu 12.04.

Apparently, Ubuntu 13.10 is doing so well on resource consumption that it even works on really ancient and slow PCs.

Comment: fixed @psny18. i've found this generally true.

Comment: Good to hear there isn't much of a loss, at least. About how much extra time can I expect? (I currently get ~ 3 hours, maybe a bit more, depending on what I'm doing) Is it worth upgrading for or should I stick with the LTS?